# Prevent whole word search from matching colon

Tags: vim

When my cursor is on a word in normal mode, and I press '*', vim searches for the word in the document.  But, if the word ends with a colon, vim includes the colon in its matching.  How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: What version of vim are you using? I can't repeat the problem on 7.3.

Comment: @Ash: It must be a setting that one of my add-ons is changing.  I just can't find the setting!  I'm using 7.3 of MacVim.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The characters that are included in such a search are specified by the 'iskeyword' option. The default value does not include `:` so the `:` must have been added by some configuration file, probably a filetype plugin. To find out what last set the value, execute

```
:verbose set iskeyword?
```

If it was set by a filetype plugin, the author presumably thought doing so would help. If you don't like it that way, you can remove the `:` by creating a file, `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim` for Unix or `~\vimfiles\after\ftplugin\<filetype>.vim` for Windows, where `<filetype>.vim` is the file named in the `:verbose` output, and put in it this line:

```
setlocal iskeyword-=:
```

See also:

```
:help *
:help 'iskeyword'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the file named in the `:verbose` output?
`:verbose set iskeyword?` returns `iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,: `. Just
`:verbose` prints nothing.

Comment: The value you show for `iskeyword` is neither the `vim` default nor the `vi` default, so it was set someplace. If `:verbose set iskeyword?` is not showing a file name, then you are probably running a version of vim that was built without the `+eval` feature. That would be the case if your are running the `tiny` or `small` version. To check that, execute `:version` from within vim and look for `+eval` or `-eval` in the output.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) It states `+eval`, though

Comment: Woops, it now outputs it! "Last set from ~/.vimrc". I have to clarify that I did add `set iskeyword-=:` to my `.vimrc` before and that seemed to fix the issue. I have removed it from there and restarted gVim, but it still claims it was last set from there. Seems to work now, though :S

Comment: `:verbose set iskeyword?` will say it was last set from `~/.vimrc` if your `~/.vimrc` contains `set compatible` or `set nocompatible`. Plugins are normally executed *after* your `~/.vimrc`, so I'm surprised that setting `iskeyword` in your `~/.vimrc` would have an effect on this problem. In any case, I'm glad it's working.